# How is tiltmeter data processed?

Tags: volcanology, measurements, data-analysis

With what programs can inclinometer data be processed? And how is instrumental correction done?

Comment: What kind of tilt data are you dealing with' Just tilt? Or 3-axis magnetometer plus 3-axis accelerometer/tilt data?? 
Is it a borehole string of tilt meters?

Comment: There are several software packages that people use. One example: http://www.geokon.com/SiteMaster